# My Tkinter program doesn't display buttons

Tags: python, tkinter

I need to make two classes within my Tkinter calculator program.
I am unsure as to how classes work, and my buttons won't appear on the program. I'm trying to learn how to use classes.

My intention is to have one class containing the dimensions of the GUI and the functions to calculate sums and to input numbers. The second class creates the buttons, sets the way they look and their positions.

Here is my first class, (the one that contains dimensions of calculator, the functions to carry out equations and input for buttons):

```
from tkinter import *

class MyFirstGUI:
    def __init__(self, calculator):
        self.calculator = calculator
        calculator.title("Calculator")
        calculator.geometry("350x460")
        
        txt=StringVar()
        expression= ""
        
        def click(num):
        
            # point out the global expression variable
            global expression
        
            # concatenation of string
            expression = expression + str(num)
        
            # update the expression by using set method
            txt.set(expression)
        # Function to evaluate the final expression
        
        def equal():
            # Try and except statement is used
            # for handling the errors like zero
            # division error etc.
        
            # Put that code inside the try block
            # which may generate the error
            try:
                # eval function evaluate the expression
                # and str function convert the result
                # into string
                global expression
                # e1.delete(0,END)
                add = str(eval(expression))
                txt.set(add)
                # initialize the expression variable
                # by empty string
                expression = " "
        
                # if error is generate then handle
                # by the except block
            except:
                expression.set("Error")
                expression=""
        # defining a clear function
        def clr():
            # to clear an individual entry
            global expression
            length = len(txt.get())
            e1.delete(length - 1, 'end')
        
        def backspace(self):
            global expression
            numLen=len(entDisplay.get())
            entDisplay.delete(numLen -1, 'end')
            if numLen == 1:
                entDisplay.insert(0, "0")
        
        def clearAll():
            # for all text to be cleared
            global expression
            expression = ""
            txt.set("")
```

Here is the second class to create and position buttons:

```
class Buttons:
    def __init__(self):
        self.frame1=frame1
        self.frame2=frame2
        frame1=Frame(self,width=390,height=100,bg="white")
        frame1.pack(side=TOP)
        frame2=Frame(self,width=390,height=368,bg="#F7A43A")
        frame2.pack(side=BOTTOM)
        # creating a label
        l1=Label(frame1,text="Basic Calculator",font=("Arial Bold",20))
        l1.pack(side=TOP,expand=YES)
        # creating an entry field
        e1=Entry(frame1,textvariable=txt,width=30,bd=10,font=("Arial Bold",12),
                 fg="black",bg="#F7BD7B",relief=RIDGE,justify=RIGHT)
        e1.pack(side=TOP)
        e1.insert(0,"0")        
    
        but1=Button(frame2,padx=14,pady=14,bd=4,fg="white",bg='#F78C19',
                    command=lambda:click(7),text="7",font=("Courier New",16,'bold'))
        
        but1.place(x=5,y=10)
        
        but2=Button(frame2,padx=14,pady=14,bd=4,fg="white",bg='#F78C19',
                    command=lambda:click(4),text="4",font=("Courier New",16,'bold'))
        but2.place(x=5,y=81)
        
        but3=Button(frame2,padx=14,pady=14,bd=4,fg="white",bg='#F78C19',
                    command=lambda:click(1),text="1",font=("Courier New",16,'bold'))
        but3.place(x=5,y=152)
        
        but4=Button(frame2,padx=48,pady=14,bd=4,fg="white",bg='#F78C19',
                    command=lambda:click(0),text="0",font=("Courier New",16,'bold'))
        but4.place(x=5,y=223)
        
        but5=Button(frame2,padx=14,pady=14,bd=4,fg="white",bg='#F78C19',
                    command=lambda:click(8),text="8",font=("Courier New",16,'bold'))
        but5.place(x=72,y=10)
        
        but6=Button(frame2,padx=14,pady=14,bd=4,fg="white",bg='#F78C19',
                    command=lambda:click(5),text="5",font=("Courier New",16,'bold'))
        but6.place(x=72,y=81)
        
        but7=Button(frame2,padx=14,pady=14,bd=4,fg="white",bg='#F78C19',
                    command=lambda:click(2),text="2",font=("Courier New",16,'bold'))
        but7.place(x=72,y=152)
        
        but8=Button(frame2,padx=14,pady=14,bd=4,fg="white",bg='#F78C19',
                    command=lambda:click("."),text=".",font=("Courier New",16,'bold'))
        but8.place(x=139,y=223)
        
        but9=Button(frame2,padx=14,pady=14,bd=4,fg="white",bg='#F78C19',
                    command=lambda:click(9),text="9",font=("Courier New",16,'bold'))
        but9.place(x=139,y=10)
        
        but10=Button(frame2,padx=14,pady=14,bd=4,fg="white",bg='#F78C19',
                     command=lambda:click(6), text="6", font=("Courier New", 16,'bold'))
        but10.place(x=139,y=81)
        
        but11=Button(frame2,padx=14,pady=14,bd=4,fg="white",bg='#F78C19',
                     command=lambda:click(3),text="3",font=("Courier New",16,'bold'))
        but11.place(x=139,y=152)
        
        but12=Button(frame2,padx=14,pady=14,bd=4,fg="white",bg='#F78C19',
                     command=lambda:click("+"),text="+",font=("Courier New",16,'bold'))
        but12.place(x=205,y=10)
        
        but13=Button(frame2,padx=14,pady=14,bd=4,fg="white",bg='#F78C19',
                     command=lambda:click("-"),text="-",font=("Courier New",16,'bold'))
        but13.place(x=205,y=81)
        
        but14=Button(frame2,padx=14,pady=14,bd=4,fg="white",bg='#F78C19',
                     command=lambda:click("*"),text="x",font=("Courier New",16,'bold'))
        but14.place(x=205,y=152)
        
        but15=Button(frame2,padx=14,pady=14,bd=4,fg="white",bg='#F78C19',
                     command=lambda:click("/"),text="/",font=("Courier New",16,'bold'))
        but15.place(x=205,y=223)
        
        but16=Button(frame2,padx=14,pady=84,bd=4,fg="black",bg='#F78C19',
                     command=clr,text="CE",font=("Courier New",16,'bold'))
        but16.place(x=270,y=10)
        
        but17=Button(frame2,padx=153,pady=14,bd=4,fg="black",bg='#F78C19',
                     command=equal,text="=",font=("Courier New",16,'bold'))
        but17.place(x=5,y=294)
        
        but18=Button(frame2,padx=14,pady=14,bd=4,fg="black",bg='#F78C19',
                     command=clearAll,text="CA",font=("Courier New",16,'bold'))
        but18.place(x=270,y=223)
                    

root = Tk()
my_gui = MyFirstGUI(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You have never created an instance of `Buttons` class.  But the code of `Buttons` class should fail to run due to errors.

Comment: It is better to use a function for the buttons instead of class

Comment: Most of the methods in the `MyFirstGUI` class are indented wrong. They should not be inside the `__init__` method.

Comment: Actually it looks like those shouldn't even be in the class, they're ordinary functions.

Comment: Please try to create a [mcve]. It should be possible to reproduce this problem with far fewer widgets.

Answer (score -1):

> My tkinter program doesn't display buttons.
> That why you had this.

```
command=lambda:click(7),...
```

You could called `MyFirstGUI` to second class and add `self` in parameter. It should be:

```
def click(self, num):
...

command=lambda:MyFirstGUI.click(self, 7), ...
```

So that you can see GUI interfaces.

So for now, all functions will not work except the `click` function.

So the rest of the functions may not work. Too many errors.

> I'm trying to learn how to use classes. The intention is to have one
> class containing the dimensions of the GUI and the functions to
> calculate sums and to input numbers.

The problem can be fix.

- In line 12, add `self` to `self.txt = StringVar()`
- Move all functions such as `click`, `equal`, `clr`, `clearAll` to
  `Buttons`'s class.
- Add `self` in parameter `click`, `equal`, `clr`, `clearAll` functions.
- Add `self` in command keyword `command=lambda:self.click` for every
  Button widgets.

Don't use wildcard `from tkinter import *`

Use `import tkinter as tk`. The do prefix `tk.` for Every widgets.

Snippet re-wrote:

```
import tkinter as tk


expression= ""
#first class that contains dimensions of calculator, the functions to carry out equations and input for buttons
class MyFirstGUI:
    def __init__( calculator):
        self.calculator = calculator
        calculator.title("Calculator")
        calculator.geometry("350x460")
        
        self.txt = StringVar()
                 
     
#second class to create and position buttons
class Buttons:
    def __init__(self, frame1):
        self.frame1=frame1
        self.frame2=frame1
        frame1 = tk.Frame(self.frame1,width=390,height=100,bg="white")
        frame1.pack(side=tk.TOP)
        frame2 = tk.Frame(self.frame2,width=390,height=368,bg="#F7A43A")
        frame2.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM)
        self.txt = tk.StringVar()
        # creating a label
        l1 = tk.Label(frame1, text="Basic Calculator", font=("Arial Bold",20))
        l1.pack(side=tk.TOP, expand=tk.YES)
        # creating an entry field
        self.e1 = tk.Entry(frame1, textvariable=self.txt, width=30, bd=10, font=("Arial Bold",12),
                 fg="black", bg="#F7BD7B", relief=tk.RIDGE, justify=tk.RIGHT)
        self.e1.pack(side=tk.TOP)
        self.e1.insert(0,"0")
         
    
        but1 = tk.Button(frame2, padx=14, pady=14, bd=4, fg="white", bg='#F78C19',
                    command=lambda:self.click( 7), text="7", font=("Courier New",16,'bold'))
        
        but1.place(x=5, y=10)
        
        but2 = tk.Button(frame2, padx=14, pady=14, bd=4, fg="white", bg='#F78C19',
                    command=lambda:self.click( 4), text="4", font=("Courier New",16,'bold'))
        but2.place(x=5,y=81)
        
        but3 = tk.Button(frame2, padx=14, pady=14, bd=4, fg="white", bg='#F78C19',
                    command=lambda:self.click( 1), text="1", font=("Courier New",16,'bold'))
        but3.place(x=5, y=152)
        
        but4 = tk.Button(frame2,padx=48,pady=14,bd=4,fg="white",bg='#F78C19',
                    command=lambda:MyFirstGUI.click( 0),text="0",font=("Courier New",16,'bold'))
        but4.place(x=5,y=223)
        
        but5 = tk.Button(frame2, padx=14, pady=14, bd=4, fg="white", bg='#F78C19',
                    command=lambda:self.click( 8), text="8", font=("Courier New",16,'bold'))
        but5.place(x=72,y=10)
        
        but6 = tk.Button(frame2, padx=14, pady=14, bd=4, fg="white", bg='#F78C19',
                    command=lambda:self.click( 5), text="5", font=("Courier New",16,'bold'))
        but6.place(x=72, y=81)
        
        but7 = tk.Button(frame2,padx=14,pady=14,bd=4,fg="white",bg='#F78C19',
                    command=lambda:self.click( 2),text="2",font=("Courier New",16,'bold'))
        but7.place(x=72, y=152)
        
        but8 = tk.Button(frame2, padx=14, pady=14, bd=4, fg="white", bg='#F78C19',
                    command=lambda:self.click( "."),text=".",font=("Courier New",16,'bold'))
        but8.place(x=139,y=223)
        
        but9 = tk.Button(frame2,padx=14,pady=14,bd=4,fg="white",bg='#F78C19',
                    command=lambda:self.click(9), text="9", font=("Courier New",16,'bold'))
        but9.place(x=139,y=10)
        
        but10 = tk.Button(frame2, padx=14, pady=14, bd=4, fg="white", bg='#F78C19',
                     command=lambda:self.click( 6), text="6", font=("Courier New", 16,'bold'))
        but10.place(x=139,y=81)
        
        but11 = tk.Button(frame2, padx=14, pady=14, bd=4,fg="white",bg='#F78C19',
                     command=lambda:self.click( 3), text="3",font=("Courier New",16,'bold'))
        but11.place(x=139, y=152)
        
        but12 = tk.Button(frame2, padx=14, pady=14, bd=4,fg="white", bg='#F78C19',
                     command=lambda:self.click( "+"), text="+",font=("Courier New",16,'bold'))
        but12.place(x=205, y=10)
        
        but13 = tk.Button(frame2, padx=14, pady=14, bd=4,fg="white", bg='#F78C19',
                     command=lambda:self.click( "-"), text="-",font=("Courier New",16,'bold'))
        but13.place(x=205, y=81)
        
        but14 = tk.Button(frame2,padx=14, pady=14, bd=4,fg="white", bg='#F78C19',
                     command=lambda:self.click( "*"), text="x", font=("Courier New",16,'bold'))
        but14.place(x=205, y=152)
        
        but15 = tk.Button(frame2,padx=14,pady=14,bd=4,fg="white",bg='#F78C19',
                     command=lambda:self.click( "/"), text="/",font=("Courier New",16,'bold'))
        but15.place(x=205,y=223)
        
        but16 = tk.Button(frame2,padx=14,pady=84, bd=4, fg="black", bg='#F78C19',
                     command=self.clr,text="CE", font=("Courier New",16,'bold'))
        but16.place(x=270,y=10)
        
        but17 = tk.Button(frame2, padx=153, pady=14, bd=4,fg="black", bg='#F78C19',
                     command=self.equal,text="=", font=("Courier New",16,'bold'))
        but17.place(x=5, y=294)
        
        but18 = tk.Button(frame2 ,padx=14, pady=14, bd=4,fg="black", bg='#F78C19',
                     command=self.clearAll,text="CA", font=("Courier New",16,'bold'))
        but18.place(x=270, y=223)


    def click(self, num):
    
        # point out the global expression variable
        global expression
    
        # concatenation of string
        expression = expression + str(num)
    
        # update the expression by using set method
        self.txt.set(expression)
                    
    def equal(self):
        # Try and except statement is used
        # for handling the errors like zero
        # division error etc.
    
        # Put that code inside the try block
        # which may generate the error
        try:
            # eval function evaluate the expression
            # and str function convert the result
            # into string
            global expression
            # e1.delete(0,END)
            add = str(eval(expression))
            self.txt.set(add)
            # initialize the expression variable
            # by empty string
            expression = " "
    
            # if error is generate then handle
            # by the except block
        except:
            expression.set("Error")
            expression=""

    def clr(self):
        # to clear an individual entry
        current = self.e1.get()
        lenght = len(current)-1
        self.e1.delete(lenght, )
    
    #def backspace(self):
        #global expression
        #numLen  =len(entDisplay.get())
        #entDisplay.delete(numLen -1, 'end')
        #if numLen == 1:
            #entDisplay.insert(0, "0")
    
    def clearAll(self):
        global expression
        expression = ""
        self.txt.set("")

            
root = tk.Tk()
my_gui = Buttons(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Screenshot:

[image]